# C# Obfuscated DLL, access members

Tags: c#, dll, .net-3.5

So I have a DLL that is obfuscated, making it impossible to use it as a reference in visual studio. I know what functions are within the DLL as they are provided for me by an API reference sheet. However an un-obfuscated DLL is not provided. Which basically means I can't write software with the library even though it was originally intended to support being used as a reference. (Visual Studio crashes, index not found) The DLL operates perfectly.

And I'm thinking outside the box. This DLL also compiles a .cs file under a specific name in the same directory, and executes it within the sub-namespace the DLL provides. Namespace is as follows:

## RootNS

- CustomRuntime
- MemberFuncs
- MemberStructs

## OtherNSNotInterestedIn

- Stuff

My question, is if it is possible to access the functions within the DLL by their names (access #**MemberFuncs**, from code executed in #**CustomRuntime**), given the facts:

1. I know the exact function names and arguments inside
2. The code being executed is within the namespace of DLL where said functions reside

In C++ this would be easy. Perhaps too it is with C#?
I would prefer to not have to hack it with a native execution within C#, since it really doesn't need to be hacked.
Thank you for any assistance!!

after VStudio crashes (window remains), the Object Browser can view the contents of the dll. So clearly it can be loaded. VStudio just won't let me compile with it as a reference.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   Dev11NonFatalError
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.50727.1
  Problem Signature 03: 5011ecaa
  Problem Signature 04: KERNELBASE.dll
  Problem Signature 05: 6.2.9200.16384
  Problem Signature 06: 5010ac2f
  Problem Signature 07: unknown
  Problem Signature 08: 00014b32
  Problem Signature 09: 80042b8c
  Problem Signature 10: CSharp
```

And here is the PEVerify (clearly the dll has a modified PE): http://pastebin.com/F3kMmyt1

Comment: Also, if I were interested in detouring a function, is it possible to do so from C# or is C++ required since the dll is obfuscated?

Comment: Wait, Without reading your question fully am going to ask you why can't you use obfuscated dll as reference? I've done without any problem. So am not getting what's wrong with it?

Comment: Visual Studio crashes as soon as the reference is loaded. The error message is "Index not found". If there is a way to load the dll in vstudio then my problem is fixed because I'll have no need to access the members manually. My end goal is and was to work within vstudio.

Unexpected error reading metadata from file '' -- 'Index not found.

Comment: But then the compiled dll works fine? Which obfuscator was used to obfuscate the dll?

Comment: obfuscation program is not specified. Whichever it is, it works quite well I must say. It changed all the registers too, so I can't even pattern scan for the functions. And yes, the dll is loaded by an executable that uses it as a reference, which too is obfuscated the same. But the DLL operates perfectly.

Comment: See edited original post above, for visual studio error information. Just says "Visual Studio has stopped working" standard windows crash dialog. VStudio remains functional.